# Android - Create an Array of Variable Object Types

Tags: android, arrays, class, object, extends

How do I create an array of different types? If each class is an extension of the `_object` class, can I just make an `_object` array and add the extensions to it?

Example:

```
class _object {
    int type = 1;
    public _object() {
        type = 2;
    }

    public doSomething() {
    }
}

class tree extends _object {
    public tree() {
    }
}

class apple extends _object {
    public apple() {
    }
}

public tree aTree = new tree();
public apple anApple = new apple();

public _object[] objects = new _object[] { aTree, anApple };
```

Comment: Did you try it? One line can give you an answer...

Comment: Actually I just came up with the last part of the question while I was asking it.

Comment: I rewrote this question like 5 times trying to simplify it. I'm trying to make a grid class that objects can register themselves to. Then objects can request a list of other objects within its grid square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in your question works. This is known as polymorphism.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Answer (score 0):

After setting up the above code in android as a project and debugging it, it in fact does work, so long as you only call methods of the base object.